# Netbeans importing projects from github

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I am trying to build this demo program (github and website below) in netbeans. I cannot seem to get it to run properly. How do i go about importing both SQLInject and SQLInject1?

SQLInject1 gives errors regarding build.xml ant files.

How do i create these projects in netbeans properly?

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/11/sql-injection-in-java-application.html?fbclid=IwAR10XX-PWMdRdhyQfce_613kmhszUZxj_gyg3h_0VJmY1dgXEAss8Ksuhcc

https://github.com/ramkicse/Sql-Injection-in-Java

Answer (score 1):

First, install git. You can do that here: https://git-scm.com/downloads

Then, clone the desired repository. You can do this by opening a git Bash shell and executing this command:

```
git clone <the repository here>
```

For example:

```
git clone https://github.com/ramkicse/Sql-Injection-in-Java.git
```

Then, open the project in NetBeans. This can be done by following the "Setting Up a Java Project Based on Existing Sources" instructions described [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/73/java/project-setup.html).

Comment: @dragonfromdreams if you are using a recent version of Netbeans you should have git client support built in directly so one step less I guess :D. This document should help https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html